# Making an object immutable in Groovy

Tags: groovy, immutability

In Groovy I can make objects immutable by doing:

```
@Immutable 
class MyObject {
   ...
}
```

But, if MyObject has a reference to a mutable object as in

```
@Immutable 
class MyObject {
    MutableObject mutableObject
}
```

I can't. I get:

```
classes only support properties with effectively immutable types including
```

But, even thou myObject has a MutableObject, the reference to it will never change.

Is there anything I can do to make `MyObject` as immutable as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure that `MutableObject` is effectively immutable you can do

```
@Immutable( knownImmutableClasses=[ MutableObject ] )
class MyObject {
    MutableObject mutableObject
}
```

Obviously care must be taken if this is a lie and mutableObject mutates ;-)